# Simple softmax classifier in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, classification, softmax, cross-entropy

So I am trying to write a simple softmax classifier in TensorFlow.

Here is the code:

```
# Neural network parameters
n_hidden_units = 500
n_classes = 10

# training set placeholders
input_X = tf.placeholder(dtype='float32',shape=(None,X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]),name="input_X")
input_y = tf.placeholder(dtype='int32', shape=(None,), name="input_y")

# hidden layer
dim = X_train.shape[1]*X_train.shape[2] # dimension of each traning data point
flatten_X = tf.reshape(input_X, shape=(-1, dim))
weights_hidden_layer = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.zeros((dim,n_hidden_units)), dtype ='float32')
bias_hidden_layer = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.zeros((1,n_hidden_units)), dtype ='float32')
hidden_layer_output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(flatten_X, weights_hidden_layer) + bias_hidden_layer)

# output layer
weights_output_layer = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.zeros((n_hidden_units,n_classes)), dtype ='float32')
bias_output_layer = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.zeros((1,n_classes)), dtype ='float32')
output_logits = tf.matmul(hidden_layer_output, weights_output_layer) + bias_output_layer
predicted_y = tf.nn.softmax(output_logits)

# loss
one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(input_y, depth=n_classes, axis = -1)
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(one_hot_labels, output_logits)

# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.01, 0.5).minimize(
    loss, var_list=[weights_hidden_layer, bias_hidden_layer, weights_output_layer, bias_output_layer])
```

This compiles, and I have checked the shape of all the tensor and it coincides with what I expect.

However, I tried to run the optimizer using the following code:

```
# running the optimizer
s = tf.InteractiveSession()
s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for i in range(5):
    s.run(optimizer, {input_X: X_train, input_y: y_train})
    loss_i = s.run(loss, {input_X: X_train, input_y: y_train})
print("loss at iter %i:%.4f" % (i, loss_i))
```

And the loss kept being the same in all iterations!

I must have messed up something, but I fail to see what.

Any ideas? I also appreciate if somebody leaves comments regarding code style and/or tensorflow tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake. You are initializing your weights using `np.zeros`. Use `np.random.normal`. You can choose `mean` for this Gaussian Distribution by using number of inputs going to a particular neuron. You can read more about it [here](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html#weight_initialization).

The reason that you want to initialize with Gaussian Distribution is because you want to break symmetry. If all the weights are initialized by `zero`, then you can use backpropogation to see that all the weights will evolved same.

Comment: I just checked using backpropogation and found out that when weights are zero, then all gradients are zero, thats why your loss was same in all iteration.

Answer (score 1):

One could visualize the weight histogram using TensorBoard to make it easier. I executed your code for this. A few more lines are needed to set up Tensorboard logging but the histogram summary of weights can be easily added.

*Initialized to zeros*

```
weights_hidden_layer = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.zeros((784,n_hidden_units)), dtype ='float32')
tf.summary.histogram("weights_hidden_layer",weights_hidden_layer)
```

[image]

*Xavier initialization*

```
initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
weights_hidden_layer = tf.Variable(initializer(shape=(784,n_hidden_units)), dtype ='float32')
tf.summary.histogram("weights_hidden_layer",weights_hidden_layer)
```

[image]